# Python: Telnetlib only commands without a space

Tags: python, telnetlib

I have some problems with the python libary telnetlib. Login works. Enable, ? and Exit works. But all commands with an space doesn't work.

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "10.159.123.91"
user = "1234"
command = "show version"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
tn.read_until("Password: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")

tn.write("enable\n")
tn.write("5678\n")
tn.write("?\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
tn.close()
```

This one is working. If I replace tn.write("?\n") with tn.write("show version\n") nothing happen.
Does anyone have any idea where my problem is?

Comment: `telnetlib` doesn't care about spaces, or anything else. When you call `write`, it just writes exactly the bytes you give it. The problem is presumably something to do with the server you're talking to over telnet.

Comment: What does `tn.write("'show version'\n")` do?

Comment: This is the output:
r1>en
Password: 
r1#'show version'
            ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

r1#exit

Comment: If I use for example "show ip int bri" I get % Incomplete command. If I use "show ip int brief" I get nothing. Then I can only stop the script with strg+c.

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution. I'm not sure if it is an good and clean solution. But it works. I add behind the command an sleep for 2 seconds.

```
import getpass
import sys
import time
import telnetlib

HOST = "10.159.123.91"
user = "1234"
command = "show version"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
tn.read_until("Password: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")

tn.write("enable\n")
tn.write("5678\n")
tn.write("show ip interface brief\n")
time.sleep(2)
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
tn.close()
```